# 32 GB SD card showing only 15 GB capacity

Tags: sd-card

I recently bought a Raspberry Pi 32 GB micro SD card. I'v connected it to my mac, and when I click on more info, it shows only 15 GB capacity. I haven't installed anything on it yet, or done anything to it at all.
How can it be it's only showing half the capacity it's supposed to have?
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!
See the photo for all the infos of the SD card.

[image: SD card info]

Comment: That is irrelevant, the sd card will be overwritten when flashing Raspberry Pi OS to the card with Pi Imager. When the Pi boots it will resize the sd card.

Comment: Presuming the card has already had an image written to it ("bought *a Raspberry Pi* 32 GB micro SD card") the information is simply wrong in a weird way -- because macOS does not support ext4 filesystems (the kind most often used by linux).  Just ignore this and put it in the Pi.

Comment: what is `Raspberry Pi 32 GB micro SD card`?

Comment: @jsotola - probably marketing words used by dodgy seller selling 16GB cards as 32GB

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility that you have been duped. There are some vendors that will sell 16 GB as 32 GB in the hope that no-one notices. And many people don't notice.

On the other hand, the card may be partitioned ans the MAC only sees the first partition. It seems that on a Mac (I don't have one), you can do

```
diskutil list
```

If would be an SD-card with a Pi-image on it, the partitioning is bizarre. I would not trust it and write a complete image over it.

On the other hand, there is 2.68 GB data on the card. So it is a second hand card anyway. It would be interesting to know what the previous owner left as data.

All in all, the following recommendations:

- Use the card only if the Pi is not mission-critical
- Write a complete new image over it
- Buy the next SD-card somewhere else.

Comment: Do you think it's a good idea to suggest that someone may have been *"duped"* based on the evidence here?

Comment: @Seamus **May** have been duped. In photography, there are many warnings about sites that sell cards with less memory than advertised. See for example https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-spot-fake-microsd-card/ or https://photographylife.com/fake-memory-cards. If it is the correct size, the partitioning is weird, you must admit. Also, if a new card has 2.68GB of data on it, that is also not normal. So yes, it is a distinct possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you `"bought a Raspberry Pi 32 GB micro SD card"`. I take that to mean that you bought a card with Raspberry Pi installed on it. The following answer assumes that's the case.

A `Raspberry Pi SD card` has (at least) two (2) *partitions*. Each of these partitions is *formatted* for a particular *file system*: one is called `FAT` or `FAT32` or `MS-DOS`, the other is called `ext4`. Your macos (the `disk utility` app?) is capable of reading FAT partitions, but **it is not** capable of reading an `ext4` partition.

In addition: I don't know what version of mac os you're using, but the `disk utility` app typically has a **device view**, and a **partition view**. It appears you are looking at the **partition view**. If that's the case, then what you are seeing in the screen shot you posted in your question, reflects only the FAT/FAT32/MS-DOS partition. It is not reporting on the `ext4` partition.

If your mac os/`disk utility` app is able to do so, you should look at the **device view** to get the total storage capacity of the device.